# Not all HTML fields are being reset by reset button

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4 and jquery. 
I have created a web page.
I have a reset button for my form.

https://jsfiddle.net/9r6zg2dt/

```
$('#productsForm').on('reset', function () {
    $("input[type='hidden']", $(this)).val('');
});
```

When I click on it, not all fields become empty.

I don't understand why all fields are not being reset.

Comment: The reset seems to be working fine. Remember that resetting the form puts all the field back to their original values as the page was loaded, it doesn't automatically clear them all. If you want the latter use `$(':input').val('');`

Comment: Side note, don't pass `$(this)` in as the context.  Just pass `this`.